# Как получить Personal access tokens через GitHub API

Tags: github-api

Подскажите пожалуйста как получить Personal access tokens через GitHub API, который в последствии мне нужно передать в headers, что-бы пользователи могли делать запросы к API GitHub без ограничений

Comment: они на то и персоальные токены, чтобы упростить жизнь тем, кому  просто нужно что-то для простейшей автоматизации о своем репозитории узнать. В более сложных кейсах используется OAuth авторизация https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#web-application-flow или авторизация через GitHubApps https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps

Comment: а после авторизация через GitHubApps как получить информацию о пользователе, что-бы передать её в headers?

Comment: там нужно один заголовок указывать `Authorization: Bearer YOUR_JWT`, где `YOUR_JWT` - это ваш JWT токен

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: я был уверен что смогу разобраться, но у меня всё ещё не получилось создать токен для пользователей. После авторизации через Git-Hub пользователь получает _/auth/complete/github/?code=XXX&state=XXX_ я попытался получить токен [таким способом](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps) но GET запрос не отправляется. помогите пожалуйста

Comment: напомните завтра о себе, пожалуйста.  я сегодня занят сильно

Comment: и укажите ЯП, на котором вы все это делаете

Comment: Пишу на Python, а для авторизации использовал [Python Social Auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/github.html)